# Joomla 3.2.0 - Facebook comments counting dynamic url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, joomla, facebook-comments

Yesterday I had some trouble with Facebook comment for Joomla 3.2.0. And for today i have to count the article's counts separately. So have the code from facebook but can't get the data-href right.

```
<span>Comments:<fb:comments-count data-href="<?=JURI::current()?>"></fb:comments-count></span>
```

So this `data-href="<?=JURI::current()?>"` is have to be changed i think. All articles have their own facebook comments so now i need is to have their own comment counting.

Question2: If there is no comment it's get just blank like Comments: ...  so is there anyway to display non commented articles to have like Comments: 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=[URL]
```

You can use `restserver.php` for getting count of share,like,comment etc

```
 <?php
     $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/Walkswithme';
     $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".$url);
     $counts = $xml->link_stat->comment_count; 
   ?>
```

for [more details](http://www.walkswithme.net/facebook-like-and-share-count-of-a-url)

where you need the comment count just use like `<?php echo $counts;?>`

Hope its helps..